# Hive regexp_extract numeric value from a string

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql, regexp-replace

I have a table as:

```
column1                         
A.A=123; B.B=124; C.C=125         
C.C=127
```

I am trying to get the numeric values from the table. The expected output is

A -> 123 / B -> 124 etc

I am trying to do using regexp_extract

Any suggestions please?

Comment: is it always going to be `a.a=1.b.b=4,x.x=55` ? is there any chance it can be `bob.bob=200`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the delimiters are fixed - '; ' between key-value pairs and '=' between key and value, you can use str_to_map function:

```
select str_to_map('A.A=123; B.B=124; C.C=125','; ','=')['A.A'] as A --returns 123
```

If you prefer regexp:

```
select 
regexp_extract('A.A=123; B.B=124; C.C=125','A.A=(\\d*)',1) as A, --returns 123
regexp_extract('A.A=123; B.B=124; C.C=125','B.B=(\\d*)',1) as B --returns 124
```

and so on

for case insensitive add `(?i)` to the regexp

```
select regexp_extract('A.A=123; b.b=124; C.C=125','(?i)B.B=(\\d*)',1) as B --returns 124
```